# What is "implementation" in Kotlin Gradle dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 Preview to start new Kotlin project. As I try to add dependencies in `build.gradle` I saw `implementation` scope instead of usual `compile`.

```
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

There's also `androidTestImplementation` and `testImplementation` scope.

In the end, I add `compile` to add third party dependencies and it works.

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

So my questions are..

- What is `implementation`, `androidTestImplementation`, and `testImplementation` scope?
- Is it any different than `compile`, `testCompile`, and `androidTestCompile`?
- Which one I should use for my Kotlin project?

Edit:
My bad, this question is not Kotlin specific. It's the new [Android Gradle Plugin configuration](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not specific to Kotlin, but has to do with the new Gradle plugin for Android.

`compile`, `provided` and `apk` are now deprecated.
Use `implementation` or `api` instead of `compile`, `compileOnly` instead of `provided`, and `runtimeOnly` instead of `apk`.

The reason for this is to speed up multi-module builds. Given module `A` which depends on module `B` which in turn depends on module `C`, a change in module `C` would trigger a recompile of module `A` as well.  If `A` does not use `C` directly, there is no need for `A` to recompile when `C` changes.

The `implementation` configuration ensures exactly this: if you specify `implementation project(':C')` in `B`, you cannot access `C` from `A` and you avoid building unnecessary modules. In a large multi-module project this can save a lot of time.

See [Migrate to the new Gradle plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#new_configurations) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier version of `gradle v3.0.0-alpha1` used to use `compile` but it has been deprecated now on.

**Why?**

Dependencies appearing in the `compile` configurations will be transitively exposed to consumers of the library, and as such will appear on the compile classpath of consumers. Dependencies found in the implementation configuration will, on the other hand, not be exposed to consumers, and therefore not leak into the consumers' compile classpath.

Let's take an example to understand this. Let's say, I created a `Library_Image_Upload` that supports `Image uploading` to the server. I used `Library_Network` lib in `Library_Image_Upload` that supports all the network operations. My library only makes use of image uploads and provide a convenient way of uploading images. Now as i used `Library_Network` lib in my `Library_Image_Upload` project, everyone using this lib will have functionality of `Image Uploading` along with all network operations **that someone may also use**(**Important**). Later on i thought there is a better alternative to `Library_Network` as `Library_Magic_Image` and used it. So all the API functions exposed by `Library_Network` are gone and **whoever is using those functions has broken build**.

`implementation` comes with several benefits:

- Dependencies do not leak into the compile classpath of consumers anymore, so you will never accidently depend on a transitive dependency
- Faster compilation thanks to reduced classpath size
- Less recompilations when implementation dependencies change: consumers would not need to be recompiled
- Cleaner publishing: when used in conjunction with the new maven-publish plugin, Java libraries produce POM files that distinguish exactly between what is required to compile against the library and what is required to use the library at runtime (in other words, don't mix what is needed to compile the library itself and what is needed to compile against the library).

To learn more read [The Java Library Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html)

So i think you have the answer of all three questions.

I hope it helps.